# Verifying binary content with WatiN

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, watin

I'm testing a site that serves up some binary (i.e. non-HTML) content. Some links directly deliver custom images, other links custom PDF's.

I'm building test cases in WatiN and NUnit. Wondering if there's a way, using WatiN to get it load a page and then get the byte[] contents of that page.

Currently, I'm just launching a WebClient to grab the content, rather than through WatiN but that's more untested code in my test suite.

Anyone else doing this and have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to skip Watin and use HttpWebRequest to grab the content straight from C# (in your test, or test library).

K Scott Allen has a blog post on getting Binary data using HttpWebrequest here: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/05/webrequest-and-binary-data.aspx

If you don't know the link target in advance (dynamically generated URLs for example), then use Watin to get the link, then HttpWebRequest to get the content.

Quote from [K Scott Allen's blog post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/05/webrequest-and-binary-data.aspx) above, should get you the Byte[] you're after

```
byte[] result;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(someUrl);

using(WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
{
   using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
   {
      using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         int count = 0;
         do
         {
            count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
         } while(count != 0);
         result = memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing. Although I used WebClient rather than WebRequest. I guess I wondered if there was something in WatiN to do this. I found I did it often enough that I just build an assertion for it.

Comment: As there seems to be no built in solution, I am marking this as the correct answer.